# Xamarin.Forms implementation of Facebook Audience Network

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, facebook-audience-network

I'm struggling with implementation of Facebook Audience Network in my Xamarin.Forms app.
Available nuget package is old and has obsolete metods.

I was able to implement ads by my own, test interstital ads are displaying correctly, but when other users are using my app ads are not displayed at all. I see in logs that FAN returned error code 1001 with "No fill" message.

What have I done:

- added to solution new Android class parse project. Project contains 'AudienceNetwork.aar` file from facebok page. Build action set to LibraryProjectZip
- I had to add some classes to fix build errors:

```
public partial class AdView
    {
        internal partial class IAdViewLoadConfigBuilderInvoker
        {
            IAdLoadAdConfig IAdLoadConfigBuilder.Build()
            {
                return Build();
            }

            IAdLoadConfigBuilder IAdLoadConfigBuilder.WithBid(string p0)
            {
                return WithBid(p0);
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class InterstitialAd
    {
        IAdLoadConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildLoadAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildLoadAdConfig();
        }

        IFullScreenAdShowConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildShowAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildShowAdConfig();
        }

        internal partial class IInterstitialAdLoadConfigBuilderInvoker
        {
            IAdLoadAdConfig IAdLoadConfigBuilder.Build()
            {
                return Build();
            }

            IAdLoadConfigBuilder IAdLoadConfigBuilder.WithBid(string p0)
            {
                return WithBid(p0);
            }
        }

        internal partial class IInterstitialAdShowConfigBuilderInvoker
        {
            IFullScreenAdShowAdConfig IFullScreenAdShowConfigBuilder.Build()
            {
                return Build();
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract partial class NativeAdBase
    {
        internal partial class INativeAdLoadConfigBuilderInvoker
        {

            IAdLoadAdConfig IAdLoadConfigBuilder.Build()
            {
                return Build();
            }

            IAdLoadConfigBuilder IAdLoadConfigBuilder.WithBid(string p0)
            {
                return WithBid(p0);
            }
        }
    }

    public partial class RewardedVideoAd
    {
        IAdLoadConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildLoadAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildLoadAdConfig();
        }

        IFullScreenAdShowConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildShowAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildShowAdConfig();
        }

        internal partial class IRewardedVideoAdLoadConfigBuilderInvoker
        {
            IAdLoadAdConfig IAdLoadConfigBuilder.Build()
            {
                return Build();
            }

            IAdLoadConfigBuilder IAdLoadConfigBuilder.WithBid(string p0)
            {
                return WithBid(p0);
            }
        }

        internal partial class IRewardedVideoAdShowConfigBuilderInvoker
        {
            IFullScreenAdShowAdConfig IFullScreenAdShowConfigBuilder.Build()
            {
                return Build();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public abstract partial class AdComponentFrameLayout
    {
        public void SetLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p0)
        {
            SetLayoutParams(p0);
        }
    }

    public abstract partial class AdNativeComponentView
    {
        public void SetLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p0)
        {
            SetLayoutParams(p0);
        }
    }

    internal partial class IInterstitialAdApiInvoker
    {
        IAdLoadConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildLoadAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildLoadAdConfig();
        }

        IFullScreenAdShowConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildShowAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildShowAdConfig();
        }
    }

    public partial class InitSettingsBuilder
    {
        AudienceNetworkAds.IInitSettingsBuilder AudienceNetworkAds.IInitSettingsBuilder.WithInitListener(AudienceNetworkAds.IInitListener p0)
        {
            return WithInitListener(p0);
        }

        AudienceNetworkAds.IInitSettingsBuilder AudienceNetworkAds.IInitSettingsBuilder.WithMediationService(string p0)
        {
            return WithMediationService(p0);
        }

        AudienceNetworkAds.IInitSettingsBuilder AudienceNetworkAds.IInitSettingsBuilder.WithPlacementIds(IList<string> p0)
        {
            return WithPlacementIds(p0);
        }
    }

    internal partial class IRewardedVideoAdApiInvoker
    {
        IAdLoadConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildLoadAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildLoadAdConfig();
        }

        IFullScreenAdShowConfigBuilder IFullScreenAd.BuildShowAdConfig()
        {
            return BuildShowAdConfig();
        }
    }
```

- in Android project in MainActivity:
  `AudienceNetworkAds.Initialize(this);`
- InterstitialAdsRenderer

```
public class InterstitalAdsRenderer : IInterstitalAdsService
    {
        InterstitialAd _interstitial;

        public void Show(string adsId)
        {
            //AdSettings.AddTestDevice("fe9823bf-946e-4a43-b38c-f958d0bfaa31");
            _interstitial = new InterstitialAd(Application.Context, adsId);
            var loadAdConfig = _interstitial.BuildLoadAdConfig()
                .WithAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener(_interstitial))
                .Build();
            _interstitial.LoadAd(loadAdConfig);
        }
    }

    internal class InterstitialAdListener : Java.Lang.Object, IInterstitialAdListener
    {
        private readonly InterstitialAd _interstitial;

        public InterstitialAdListener(InterstitialAd interstitial)
        {
        }

        public void OnAdClicked(IAd p0)
        {
        }

        public void OnAdLoaded(IAd p0)
        {
            _interstitial.Show();
        }

        public void OnError(IAd p0, AdError p1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnError: " + p1.ErrorMessage);
        }

        public void OnLoggingImpression(IAd p0)
        {
        }

        public void OnInterstitialDismissed(IAd p0)
        {
        }

        public void OnInterstitialDisplayed(IAd p0)
        {
        }
    }
```

As I said earlier test ads in test device(emulator added to testsDevices) is displaying ads correctly, but on the production there is no ads :/

Anyone had implemented facebok ads in Xamarin.Forms project and can tell me how can I do this correctly?

Comment: "I had to add some classes to fix build error" - what classes?  What build errors?  There is NO code in your post.  We have no idea what you're actually doing.  I'm not going to take the time to watch a youtube video to understand what you're doing.  Please read [ask] before posting.

Comment: @Jason Sorry for that, I Added piece of code responsible for displaying ads.

Answer (score 0):

this error normally means that you have not logged in to Facebook app or Facebook app is not available in the device that you are running your app